# Writing payload to a file and transport using SFTP

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-component

I have a requirement when I am transforming DB records to XML using dataweave and records are huge in number (approx. 95k) due to which it is difficult to process such big data.

Now I want to write this XML data which is my payload to a file and transport it using SFTP to the proxy system so the proxy will download the file and read the data.

How can I achieve this? Can we use SFTP connector to write payload in a text file or some other connector is required ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can Set payload with incurring payload which will be output of your dataweave.
then using sftp outbound endpoint write with filename and Extension you need.
Enable streaming in sftp endpoint so i can process huge amount of data efficiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set payload` with the data that you want to write in the file. Then use `Object-to-String transformer` and call SFTP Connector providing the outbound sftp details.